# projecting nonlinear functions into high dimensional spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, neural-networks

Recently I read a paper on deep neural networks which explained that the ReLU activation function $f(x) = max(0,x)$ which is piece-wise linear is highly-effective within large networks because input data that is projected into high dimensional spaces allows linear representations of a nonlinear function. However, they don't mention the theorem they use.

After more reflection I think this makes sense because any real-valued continuous function is linear in the infinite dimensional space consisting of continuous functions. Having said this, I don't remember being taught a theorem from which such conclusions may be drawn.

Might someone know the standard name for this theorem? I'm very interested in generalisations of this theorem.

**X. Glorot et al. Deep Sparse Rectifier Neural Networks. 2011.**

Answer (score 0):

Is [Universal Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) what you're looking for?

Comment: No, although the capacity of neural networks as complex function approximators might be a special consequence of the result I'm looking for.